# How to get the post editor and media library to respect HTTPS administration mode?

Tags: wp-admin, media-library, ssl

I have a site with FORCE_SSL_ADMIN turned on. When I'm editing a post with an embedded image, or when I'm viewing images through the media library, they are loaded using the http:// protocol rather than https. This causes a mixed-content warning in IE, which clients kind of freak out about.

Does anyone have a recommended approach for finding/replacing these non-secure image URLs while viewing them through the admin?

The frontend loads over regular http, so I don't want to do any replacing in the DB that will force images to load over https outside of the admin.

I figure this has to be a common problem, so I'd appreciate any advice, even if it's "you can't do that".

Comment: Please report the issue on wordpress trac: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't right now. This needs to be fixed in wordpress core. Probably this can be temporarily circumvented for a fraction of the problems with a plugin, but it's much more valuable to invest the time developing something in an actual fix of wordpress.

Comment: Thanks @hakre. I checked trac, and coincidentally it looks like someone filed the underlying issue a couple days ago (http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15928). Hopefully it'll be worked into a coming release! I find it a bit weird that more people haven't had this problem though... maybe SSL administration isn't as widely used as I assumed.

Answer (score 3):

Thankfully the fix for [core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15928](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15928) is scheduled to be included in the next release.
Until then, you can use the following code as a work-around. ( *Props to [Andrew Tetlaw](http://www.sitepoint.com/crimes-against-wordpress/) for the fix.* )

Add it to your theme's functions.php file, or put in a file (i.e. fix_ssl.php ) and place it in your wp-content/mu-plugins folder.

```
function fix_ssl_siteurl($url) {
  if ( 0 === strpos($url, 'http') && is_ssl() )
    $url = str_replace( 'http://', 'https://', $url );
  return $url;
}
add_filter('option_siteurl', 'fix_ssl_siteurl');
add_filter('option_home', 'fix_ssl_siteurl');
add_filter('option_url', 'fix_ssl_siteurl');
add_filter('option_wpurl', 'fix_ssl_siteurl');
add_filter('option_stylesheet_url', 'fix_ssl_siteurl');
add_filter('option_template_url', 'fix_ssl_siteurl');
```

Comment: Unfortunately the ticket mentioned didn't get into 3.3 after all.  I'll be pushing for 3.4

Comment: Still an issue as of WP 4.1. Ticket was active toward end of release cycle but didn't make it in.